# знаки препинания!

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, верно ли расставлены знаки препинания в данном предложении:
"Стоимость путевки для сопровождающего лица продолжительностью 21 день, со сроком заезда в сентябре-октябре 2015 года, при условии проживания в 2-местном номере со всеми удобствами составит 100 рублей". Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаемые варианты:

(1) Для сопровождающего лица стоимость путевки  продолжительностью 21 день, со сроком заезда в сентябре-октябре 2015 года, при условии проживания в 2- местном номере со всеми удобствами составит 100 рублей.

(2) Стоимость путевки для сопровождающего лица (продолжительностью 21 день, со сроком заезда в сентябре-октябре 2015 года, при условии проживания в 2- местном номере со всеми удобствами) составит 100 рублей".

Вообще говоря, окончательная редакция зависит от контекста, но в любом случае лучше разделить  несогласованные определения разной тематики.